# Beamer: How to remove shadow under the title on a given frame?

Tags: latex, title, shadow, beamer

On one particular frame I would like to remove the shadow that the theme I am using inserts under the title. The reason is that with a black background (which I use only on this frame), it looks quite ugly.

Do you have any idea can I do that? I've managed to remove the shadow under a block environment, thanks to:

> \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]%
>   [shadow=false]

but I could not find a similar thing for \titleframe (except one that you can only put in your preamble - which would not help, in my case).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: this belongs here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/. I'm not angry, just pointing you to where you need to ask the question.

Comment: Oh, thank you actually: I did not know about this. I will certainly prove to be useful. Still, if someone knows a workaround for this matter, I would be glad.

Comment: @rubenvb: latex question continue to be on-topic here for people who prefer (for whatever reason) to post them. TeX, LaTeX and Friends is available, and I would recommend it, but this question is fine on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Those interested will find two working solutions here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/beamer-how-to-remove-shadow-under-the-title-on-a-given-frame

I personally prefer the one that fixes the way shadowing works but a way to remove it is also proposed.

NB: sorry, I am not yet allowed to add a comment (but as this is an answer, I guess it's fine).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use beamer version 3.51 (exactly this version, not newer, not older) with pdflatex. This is the one unique version in which the problem with shadow does not exist:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you know why the issue came back on later versions?

Comment: @anderstood The fix for this problem caused problems for xelatex users, so it was reversed.